# Default radio button value from constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a constant setup for ROLES (a field_name in the User table). I am trying to make 'employee', or [2], from the array become the default radio button value in the form, an absoluate value — if a new role is added in the future, it wouldn't affect this.

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # -- Constants ------------------------------------------------------------

  ADMIN = 'admin'
  MANAGER = 'manager'
  EMPLOYEE = 'employee'
  ROLES = [ADMIN, MANAGER, EMPLOYEE]
end
```

**_form.html.haml**

```
- if @user && current_user.is_admin?
  = form.radio_button :role, (User.non_admin_roles), checked: true
```

**non_admin_roles on User.rb**

```
def self.non_admin_roles
    User::ROLES.select { |r| r != ADMIN }
end
```

How can I select the 'employee' value to be checked? I can set it in the `user_controller` but I would prefer to set it in the _form if possible.

```
def new 
@user.role = User::ROLES[2]
end
```

Comment: Actually, setting the role in the controller (as seen in the end of my post) isn't great. It doesn't let you create a user with the role as `manager`

Comment: Iterate over your `Post::ROLES` constant, assign the block value as the second parameter after specifying the `radio_button` name, set the `checked` attribute as a boolean value checking if the block value is equal to `employee` there you have your `radio_button` checked if the value is employee. `self.non_admin_roles` is useless in such case.